# GeoServer OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS available options?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding OpenLayers documentation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6995/understanding-openlayers-documentation)

I'm trying to use OpenLayers as part of OpenGeo to display WFS data.

My data isn't displaying and I am having trouble finding out what options are available to the OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS class. The help just says

> Parameters:
>
> options   {Object} Optional
>   object whose properties will be set on
>   the instance.

...and doesn't give any information as to what options are available. Google just came up with the same quote.

This is really hard to debug as I'm not getting any errors - even if I type in stuff that I know is wrong - the data is just not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Options are defined as attributes into the class. You can see them looking into the [code](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS/v1.js).
You can also check the source code of examples, like [that one](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html). But there is [many](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/). Just make a search on *wfs*.